# C Linker optimization with libraries

Tags: c

Suppose I have a function foo() in some C library and I am statically linking this library to some executable, but there is no call to this method from library or from the code within the executable. 
Will linker optimize the final executable by removing the function definition or will it still be the part of code?
Is there any linker optimization which can turn on/off this behavior?

Comment: Are you asking about specific toolchain or in general (in which case answer is: it depends on your toolchain)?

Comment: You'll have to specify which linker on which operating system you mean.

Comment: For the vast majority of systems out there: no, a function which is not called (or have its address taken) will not be linked.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ when asking questions about C.

Comment: I guess the answer would be: There exist linkers which turn such behavior on/off.

Comment: Link-time optimization is actually a *compiler* thing. See [Link Time Optimization in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html)

Comment: C doesn't support _methods_.

Comment: @user694733 I am asking in general, not specific to a compiler, but by looking at the answers it seems, it is a compiler specific thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should depend on your toolchain, however
my gcc-7 does not include it.

You can easily test it with `objdump`

```
//foo.h
#pragma once
int foo(int x);
int foo2(int x);

//foo.c
#include "foo.h"
int foo(int x) {
    return x * 2; //whatever
}
int foo2(int x) {
    return x * 2; //whatever
}

//test.c
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    //foo(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Build the static libary with

```
gcc -c foo.c
ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
```

You can view the result with

```
objdump -j .text -S libfoo.a
```

It should look like this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   a:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
   c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   d:   c3                      retq   

000000000000000e <foo2>:
   e:   55                      push   %rbp
   f:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  12:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  15:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  18:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
  1b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1c:   c3                      retq
```

However after building `gcc test.c libfoo.a`
it does not appear in the executable.

```
objdump -j .text -x a.out

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000000004f0 l    d  .text  0000000000000000              .text
0000000000000520 l     F .text  0000000000000000              deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000560 l     F .text  0000000000000000              register_tm_clones
00000000000005b0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              __do_global_dtors_aux
00000000000005f0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              frame_dummy
0000000000000680 g     F .text  0000000000000002              __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000610 g     F .text  0000000000000065              __libc_csu_init
00000000000004f0 g     F .text  000000000000002b              _start
00000000000005fa g     F .text  000000000000000b              main
```

When you use the function in test.c, it will appear in the symbol-table.
However if the library contains multiple functions, all will be included regardless of their usage.

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000000004f0 l    d  .text  0000000000000000              .text
0000000000000520 l     F .text  0000000000000000              deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000560 l     F .text  0000000000000000              register_tm_clones
00000000000005b0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              __do_global_dtors_aux
00000000000005f0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              frame_dummy
00000000000006a0 g     F .text  0000000000000002              __libc_csu_fini
000000000000061d g     F .text  000000000000000f              foo2
0000000000000630 g     F .text  0000000000000065              __libc_csu_init
000000000000060f g     F .text  000000000000000e              foo
00000000000004f0 g     F .text  000000000000002b              _start
00000000000005fa g     F .text  0000000000000015              main
```

You can solve this issue (on gcc) with compiler flags.
(see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Compilation-options.html)

The idea is, that you build all object files with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`, which causes the creation of a unique section for each function. (Normally they are all in the same .text)

```
gcc -c foo.c -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
objdump -S libfoo.a
```

will show you this:

```
Disassembly of section .text.foo:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   a:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
   c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   d:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .text.foo2:

0000000000000000 <foo2>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   a:   c1 e0 02                shl    $0x2,%eax
   d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   e:   c3                      retq
```

Using `-Wl,--gc-sections` will enable the garbage-collection in the linking-process, in which unused sections will be ignored/removed.

```
gcc test.c libfoo.a -Wl,--gc-sections
objdump -j .text -x a.out
```

will result in this:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000000004f0 l    d  .text  0000000000000000              .text
0000000000000520 l     F .text  0000000000000000              deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000560 l     F .text  0000000000000000              register_tm_clones
00000000000005b0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              __do_global_dtors_aux
00000000000005f0 l     F .text  0000000000000000              frame_dummy
0000000000000690 g     F .text  0000000000000002              __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000620 g     F .text  0000000000000065              __libc_csu_init
000000000000060f g     F .text  000000000000000e              foo
00000000000004f0 g     F .text  000000000000002b              _start
00000000000005fa g     F .text  0000000000000015              main
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically yes, the linker should be capable of this optimization, as this is often the reason to do static linking in the first place (instead of the usually more advisable dynamic linking).